# PowerBI Dataflow: One or more tables references a dynamic data source

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I'm unable to save the dataflow if this dataflow includes a simple function

```
let
  Source = (folder as text) => let
        Source1 = Folder.Files(folder)
    in
        Source1
in
  Source
```

it refuses it to be saved with the following message:

> Cannot Save Dataflows:  One or more tables references a dynamic data source.

Can someone explain to me why this is a problem for PBI Dataflow to accept the function above ?

I'm trying to loop folders to get as many files as I can, works ok in PBI Desktop, but in dataflows I'm facing this particular problem.

Thank you

Comment: I run into this error when attempting to download a file from a website, when the file URL was scraped off the website first (not hard-coded). There is a Microsoft Idea to change this behaviour: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=a7a0a817-75bc-4482-9070-72dfead8f5b6